How to collect traces generated inside a container with LTTng?
I'm trying to find the most convenient and maintainable LTTng setups supporting collection of traces generated from a container.
Here is what I've tried:
host:

lttng-sessoind (root/user)
lttng-relayd (root/user)

container:

liblttng-ust executable

I create snapshot and live sessions on the host which filter traces containing a specific field. Inside the containers I just generate traces.
To achieve this, I start the container like this:
podman run \
    -v /var/run/lttng:/var/run/lttng \
    -v /dev/shm/lttng-ust-wait-8:/dev/shm/lttng-ust-wait-8 \
    -e LTTNG_HOME=/root \
    image-with-liblttng-ust

The image-with-liblttng-ust image is any image which has an executable producing traces with liblttng-ust.
Here is an example of the setup where the lttng-sessiond is started under a non-root user:
podman run \
    -v /home/username/.lttng:/var/run/lttng \
    -v /dev/shm/lttng-ust-wait-8-1000:/dev/shm/lttng-ust-wait-8 \
    -e LTTNG_HOME=/root \
    image-with-liblttng-ust

The first mount doesn't look bad, the runtime LTTng directory is mounted to establish communication between lttng-sessiond and liblttng-ust, nevertheless it could be enough to mount only /home/username/.lttng/lttng-ust-sock-8 for the maintainability IMO mount of the whole directory is better.
The second mount isn't that nice, it's outside the runtime directory, it's not a directory but a specific shared memory file containing the ABI version and the uid in the name, every LTTng update would require verification of the file name.
I've also tried various mount combinations:
+-----------------------+------------------+--------------------------------+-----------------------------+-------+
| HOST RUNDIR           | CONTAINER RUNDIR | HOST SHM                       | CONTAINER SHM               | WORKS |
+-----------------------+------------------+--------------------------------+-----------------------------+-------+
| /home/username/.lttng | /root/.lttng     | /dev/shm/lttng-ust-wait-8-1000 | /dev/shm/lttng-ust-wait-8-0 | yes   |
+-----------------------+------------------+--------------------------------+-----------------------------+-------+
| /home/username/.lttng | /var/run/lttng   | /dev/shm/lttng-ust-wait-8-1000 | /dev/shm/lttng-ust-wait-8   | yes   |
+-----------------------+------------------+--------------------------------+-----------------------------+-------+
| /var/run/lttng        | /var/run/lttng   | /dev/shm/lttng-ust-wait-8      | /dev/shm/lttng-ust-wait-8   | yes   |
+-----------------------+------------------+--------------------------------+-----------------------------+-------+
| /var/run/lttng        | /root/.lttng     | /dev/shm/lttng-ust-wait-8      | /dev/shm/lttng-ust-wait-8-0 | no    |
+-----------------------+------------------+--------------------------------+-----------------------------+-------+
| /home/username/.lttng | /root/.lttng     | /dev/shm/lttng-ust-wait-8-1000 | /dev/shm/lttng-ust-wait-8   | no    |
+-----------------------+------------------+--------------------------------+-----------------------------+-------+

Is this a valid approach to enable container support? Are there any better options?

Here is some information and ideas. I haven't tested through all of these, but I think the options are copacetic.
LTTng Connection Paths
In LTTng-UST 2.13, there two connection paths are referred to as "global apps"1 and "local apps"2.
global apps:

socket: /var/run/lttng/lttng-ust-wait-%oldest_compatible_abi_version
shm path: /dev/shm/lttng-ust-wait-%oldest_compatible_abi_version

local apps:

socket: ${LTTNG_HOME:-${HOME}}/.lttng/lttng-ust-sock-%oldest_compatible_abi_version
shm path: /dev/shm/lttng-ust-wait-%oldest_compatible_abi_version-%uid

Where %oldest_compatible_api_version is presently 83, and the paths are built from compile time definitions4 and runtime environment variables.
On the listening side, in LTTng-tools 2.13 the sockets and shared memory are setup as follows.
When lttng-sessiond is run as the root user5:

socket: /var/run/lttng/lttng-ust-sock-%oldest_compatible_abi_version
shm path: /dev/shm/lttng-ust-wait-%oldest_compatible_abi_version

When lttng-sessiond is run as a non-root user6:

socket: ${LTTNG_HOME:-${HOME}}/.lttng/lttng-ust-sock-%oldest_compatible_abi_version
shm path: /dev/shm/lttng-ust-wait-%oldest_compatible_abi_version-%uid

Note that LTTng-tools does not create a listening socket and shared memory path as the root user that also include the uid (e.g. lttng-ust-wait-8-0). As you saw in your tests, that didn't work. This means that UST instrumented applications run as the root user, the only possible connection is the "global apps" connection path.
Container setups
You are trying to establish the most convenient setups while running lttng-sessiond on the host in two different ways: one as the root user on the host, the other as a non-root user on the host.
For running lttng-sessiond as root on the host: the command you've described works well. You can simplify it by removing the LTTNG_HOME variable for containers running applications as the root user. While it is possible the make the command even more simple by sharing all of /dev/shm with --ipc=host, that has it's own drawbacks.
The setup with running lttng-sessiond as a non-root user on the host doesn't seem to bring many benefits. Running it as a non-root user means that you can't do any kernel tracing with that sessiond, and then the applications inside containers running as root have a complicated connection scheme. I think it would be easier to use one of the two following approaches:

Use a pod with a shared /var/run/lttng mount with one containers running lttng-sessiond as root.

Inside a podman pod /dev/shm is shared between all containers in the pod. This is similar to example setups inside a kubernetes pod8. /var/run/lttng should still be shared among the containers in the pod.
Example:
$ podman pod create -v var-run-lttng:/var/run/lttng my-pod
$ podman run --pod my-pod -v var-run-lttng:/var/run/lttng img-that-runs-lttng-sessiond-as-root
$ podman run --pod my-pod -v var-run-lttng:/var/run/lttng img-that-runs-app-instrumented-with-lttng-ust


Run lttng-sessiond in a container with a shareable IPC namespace7 and use that namespace with the application containers. /var/run/lttng should still be shared among the containers.

Example:
$ podman run -d -v var-run-lttng:/var/run/lttng --ipc=shareable img-that-runs-lttng-sessiond-as-root
xxxx   # container ID
$ podman run -v var-run-lttng:/var/run/lttng --ipc=container:xxxx img-that-runs-app-instrumented-with-lttng-ust

Potential changes in future versions
In future versions, LTTNG_UST_APP_PATH environment variables for UST applications in containers, and potentially either the proposed LTTNG_UST_CTL_PATH or the LTTNG_RUNDIR environment variables for lttng-sessiond could be used to simplify the which directories need to be shared between host and containers, but /dev/shm will still need special attention.
Other notes
The default shm size for podman containers is 64 megabytes. Depending on the number of cores on your host and your session channel configurations, it would be wise to set a larger value.
